# yyyy-mm-dd and hh:mm (PM/AM) convert into long

Tags: blackberry, java-me, date-format, simpledateformat

I have two strings:

```
String date = "2011-11-11"
String time="11:00 PM"
```

i want to merge this date and time and convert them into a long, similar to  System.currentTimeMillis().

Comment: Damn you all :D I was first :O

Comment: This question isn't materially different than your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091235/hhmm-aa-12-hour-format-convert-in-hhmm-24-hour-format

Answer (score 1):

try this it is working fine

```
 String inputDate=date+" "+time ;;
       long parsedDate = HttpDateParser.parse(inputDate);//inputDate should 2011-12-11 11:10:00 PM" formate
       System.out.println("========================="+parsedDate);
       Date date=new Date(parsedDate);
       SimpleDateFormat date1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm aa");
       String opdate=date1.format(date);
       System.out.println("========================="+opdate);
```

Comment: if String time = "02:30 PM"; m still get 02:30 AM

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateFormat and parse the String into a Date.
When you have Date you can get .getTime() what's a long

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

NOT TESTED!!

```
String date = "2011-11-11";
String time = "11:00 PM";
String toParse = date + " " + time;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm aa");
try {
    Date parse = sdf.parse(toParse);
    parse.getTime();
} catch (ParseException ex) {       
}
```

Comment: If you could use my answer please tag it:-*

Comment: hi m passing "02:30 PM" and in o/p m getting "02:30 AM" what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String dateTime = "2011-11-11 " + time;
DateFormat formatter ; 
Date date ; 
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH:MM");
date = (Date)formatter.parse(dateTime ); 
long time = date.getTime();
```

I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759036/how-to-convert-string-into-time-format-and-add-two-hours) in the same lines.

Answer (score -1):

```
String date =date+time ;
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm");
Date myDate = fmt.parse(date); 

System.out.println(myDate);  //Mon Jun 04 07:05:00 EDT 2007
long timestamp = myDate.getTime();
```