# hh:mm aa (12 hour format ) convert in HH:mm (24 hour format)

Tags: blackberry, java-me, time

I have `String time="02:30 PM"` means 12 hour format and i want to convert this time in 24 hour format .

I want this `o/p: 14:30`. so how can i convert this ?

Comment: Tag only blackberry so people only put the code for blackberry.

Comment: In first sent question has also Java tag after sometimes Java tag removed

Comment: See duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090196/yyyy-mm-dd-and-hhmm-pm-am-convert-into-long

Comment: Removed my answer - didn't realize the blackberry limitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about berries, but in case the API is missing a proper formatting function, you can always get your hands dirty with the string itself:

```
static String convert(String time){

    boolean pm = "PM".equals(time.substring(6).toUpperCase());
    int h = Integer.valueOf(time.substring(0,2));

    if (h!=12)
        h+=pm?12:0;
    else
        h=pm?h:0;
    return ((h<10)?"0":"")+h + ":" + time.substring(3,5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

This will give the current time in 24 Hours format.

```
    SimpleDateFormat formate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String newTime = formate.formatLocal(System.currentTimeMillis());
```