# How to add 10 minutes to my (String) time?

Tags: java

I have this time:

```
String myTime = "14:10";
```

Now I want to add 10 minutes to this time, so that it would be `14:20`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You will find this useful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759036/how-to-convert-string-into-time-format-and-add-two-hours

Comment: Dont Forget the quotes if you want this to be a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I say 5 seconds from now in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655357/how-do-i-say-5-seconds-from-now-in-java)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Something like this

```
 String myTime = "14:10";
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
 Date d = df.parse(myTime); 
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTime(d);
 cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
 String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
```

As a fair warning there might be some problems if daylight savings time is involved in this 10 minute period.

Comment: newTime is string , where cal.getTime() is returning date

Comment: The java date/time API is hopelessly outdated, even to the point that Joda Time might be included in future JDKs.
Please consider Jon Skeet's answer.

Comment: Exactly as I wanted.

Comment: Is it possible to do without using any additional third-party library?

Answer (score 24):

I would use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net), parse the time as a `LocalTime`, and then use

```
time = time.plusMinutes(10);
```

Short but complete program to demonstrate this:

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
        LocalTime time = formatter.parseLocalTime("14:10");
        time = time.plusMinutes(10);
        System.out.println(formatter.print(time));
    }       
}
```

Note that I would *definitely* use Joda Time instead of java.util.Date/Calendar if you possibly can - it's a *much* nicer API.

Comment: Since Java 8 there's `java.time` with a very similar API to Joda Time (heavily inspired by it) and that should be used instead.

Answer (score 13):

Use `Calendar.add(int field,int amount)` method.

Answer (score 7):

Java 7 Time API

```
    DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");

    LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse("14:10");
    System.out.println(df.format(lt.plusMinutes(10)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have it converted to a Date, where you can then add a number of seconds, and convert it back to a string.

Answer (score 1):

I used the code below to add a certain time interval to the current time.

```
    int interval = 30;  
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();

    Log.i("Time ", String.valueOf(df.format(time.getTime())));

    time.add(Calendar.MINUTE, interval);

    Log.i("New Time ", String.valueOf(df.format(time.getTime())));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the time as integers and regulate it through the division and modulo operators, once that is done convert the integers into the string format you require.

Answer (score 0):

You have a plenty of easy approaches within above answers. 
This is just another idea. You can convert it to millisecond and add the TimeZoneOffset and add / deduct the mins/hours/days etc by milliseconds.

```
String myTime = "14:10";
int minsToAdd = 10;
Date date = new Date();
date.setTime((((Integer.parseInt(myTime.split(":")[0]))*60 + (Integer.parseInt(myTime.split(":")[1])))+ date1.getTimezoneOffset())*60000);
System.out.println(date.getHours() + ":"+date.getMinutes());
date.setTime(date.getTime()+ minsToAdd *60000);
System.out.println(date.getHours() + ":"+date.getMinutes());
```

Output :

```
14:10
14:20
```

Comment: One thing I learned about doing time math the hard way is the damn leap seconds... you should never ever do time calculations based on commonly known time (ie 1 minute = 60 seconds) constants when dealing with time in java.

Comment: Thanx m0s for your comment. If you can explain the reason for "never ever do time calculations based on commonly known time (ie 1 minute = 60 seconds) constants when dealing with time in java" it would be really helpful for all of us including me.

Comment: please refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html and http://lpar.ath0.com/2008/09/16/the-fractious-leap-second-debate/ and http://tripoverit.blogspot.com/2007/07/java-calculate-difference-between-two.html