# Sequential dates and times in Java

Tags: java, date

I input a single date and obtain an ordered collection of (12-hour) timestamps where the first element is guaranteed to start on that date. The timestamps can potentially span multiple days given one input. I don't believe there are any cases where timestamps are more than 24 hours apart.

I need a way to handle the times and convert them to full dates in the case of rollover in a way such that the date increments properly.

Both the Date and Time are stored as Date objects. (my input is actually a sorted `ArrayList<Date>` as I have several hundred files to process)

For example:

```
> 2014.05.13

01:02:03 AM
10:54:21 PM
10:59:32 PM
11:34:00 PM
11:59:54 PM
12:01:00 AM
01:02:03 AM
```

I want a collection of Dates kind of like this:

```
[2014-05-13 01:02:03 AM,
2014-05-13 10:54:21 PM,
2014-05-13 10:59:32 PM,
2014-05-13 11:34:00 PM,
2014-05-13 11:59:54 PM,
2014-05-14 12:01:00 AM,
2014-05-14 01:02:03 AM]
```

What is a good way to create this collection? I am using Java 8.

---

Edit: thanks to the suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23646930/1467811 to add dates in a loop. Here's some pseudocode of my solution, since the parsing logic is a lot more complicated than this.

```
// 2014-01-21.165900-0500EST
// 2014-05-03.124529-0400EDT
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd.HHmmssZz", Locale.ENGLISH);
ArrayList<Date> logDates = new ArrayList<>();

// <snip> ... get array of dates ...

Collections.sort(logDates);

DateFormat msgDf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date lastDate;

for (Date d : logDates) {
    lastDate = d;
    Path p = GetFilePathFromDate(d);
    for (String line : Files.readAllLines(p)) { 
        String time = ExtractTimeFromLine(line); // ex. "12:01:00 AM"
        Date msgDate = msgDf.parse(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                      .format(lastDate) + " " + time);
        if (msgDate.before(lastDate)) { // must have passed over a day
            Calendar curCal = Calendar.getInstance();
            curCal.setTime(msgDate);
            curCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

            msgDate = curCal.getTime();
        }
        lastDate = msgDate;

        // msgDate now has the correct date associated with its time
        // ex. "2014-05-14 12:01:00 AM"
        // do stuff with msgDate
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you storing the dates? How are they currently being formatted/printed? Some sample code would help a lot....

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the post with a little more information. I am using Java 8, and everything is just stored as a `Date` object. I simplified the question a little bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add some time in your date and add by loop in your collection ...

you can get help how to add some time in date by following link

[Java : how to add 10 mins in my Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015536/java-how-to-add-10-mins-in-my-time)

```
 String myTime = "14:10";
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
 Date d = df.parse(myTime); 
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTime(d);
 cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
 String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: Probably you wanted to link to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9015564/821202

Answer (score 0):

Using a Set of Calendar?

```
Set<Calendar> dates = new HashSet<Calendar>();
// create specific calendar object
// add object to Set
```

Comment: Don't use the Java Date/Time API. [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be much better if your data source provided the time-of-day in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format using 24-hour clock, HH-MM-SS.

Even better, your data source should return the entire meaningful chunk of information, the date *and* the day-of-time *and* a time zone or offset altogether in standard ISO 8601 format, YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ. For example, `2016-09-26T21:57:18Z` where the `Z` is short for Zulu and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Anyways, to process your time-of-day values we must parse them. To parse, we must define a formatting pattern to match.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm:ss aa" );
```

Loop your inputs, parsing each one, and collecting them. The `LocalTime` class represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone.

```
List<LocalTime> times = new ArrayList<>();
…
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( input , formatter );
…
```

Define your initial date. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate initialDate = LocalDate.parse( "2014-05-13" );
```

Loop your collection of `LocalTime` objects, combining each one with the `LocalDate` to get a `LocalDateTime` object.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt );
```

But before combining, ask if the current `LocalTime` is less than the previous, is earlier. If so, increment the `LocalDate`.

```
if( lt.isBefore( previousLocalTime ) ) {
    ld = ld.plusDays( 1 );
…
```

Keep in mind that these `LocalDateTime` objects do *not* represent actual moments on the timeline. For an actual point in time, you must adjust them into a time zone (or offset).

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).