# How to add time to the current time?

Tags: java, java-time

I have an initial time `12:00:00` and I need to add `144` mins to it.

The expected output is `15.24.00` (i.e, adding 2.24 hours to the initial time).

How should I update the current code given below ?

```
String startTime = "13:00:00";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date date1 = null;
Date date2 = null;  
try {
    date1 = format.parse(startTime);    
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();    
}
Long addition = (long) (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(date1.getTime()));
System.out.println("Difference : "+addition);
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use the `java.time` APIs (Java 8+) or the ThreeTenBackPort libraries (Java 7-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java : how to add 10 mins in my Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015536/java-how-to-add-10-mins-in-my-time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a modern date-time API as follows :

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("13:00:00").plus(Duration.ofMinutes(144));
        System.out.println(time);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
15:24
```

Check [here](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

Convert input String to java.util.Date via implementing the following logic:

```
public static Date getDate(String source, String format) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    return dateFormat.parse(source);
}
```

Step 2:

Adding minutes to the date:

```
    public static Date add(Date date, int minute) {
       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
       calendar.setTime(date);
       calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
       return calendar.getTime();
    }
```

Step 3:

Now, If you want to convert java.util.Date back to String use following logic:

```
    public static String getDate(Date date, String format) {
       DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
       return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the below way:

```
String str = "13:00:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("kk:mm:ss");
LocalTime dateTime = LocalTime.parse(str, formatter).plusMinutes(144);
System.out.println(dateTime);
```