# How to parse time durations from Strings with 2 different Format and add them?

Tags: java

I Have 2 Strings with two different format 
e.g.
First Format : "08:50 09:50"
Second Format : "10:30"

how can i parse  & subtract the first to be 01:00 and add it to the second one after parse it to get total = 11:30

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert string into time format and add two hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759036/how-to-convert-string-into-time-format-and-add-two-hours)

Answer (score 0):

The formats are basically the same `HH:mm` which you can parse and format using SimpleDateFormat. To split the String, you can use `.split(" ")`

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work

```
String a = "08:50 09:50";
String b = "10:30";
String[] c = a.split(" ", 2);

DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");

Date t1 = sdf.parse(c[0]); 
Date t2 = sdf.parse(c[1]);
Date t3 = sdf.parse(b);

long t = (t2.getTime() - t1.getTime()) + t3.getTime();

Time time = new Time(t)
```

Comment: if it is a list of String Contains a mix of this Formats i need to calculate all in the list to get total in this format 00:00

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is minutes:seconds (if it is hour:minutes change accordignly), you can use calendars to do so :

```
String[] tokens1 = "08:50 09:50".split(" ");
String[] tokens2 = tokens[0].split(":");
int minutes1 = Integer.valueOf(tokens2[0]);
int seconds1 = Integer.valueOf(tokens2[1]);
tokens2 = tokenss[1].split(":");
int minutes2 = Integer.valueOf(tokens2[0]);
int seconds2 = Integer.valueOf(tokens2[1]);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date(0l));
cal.add(minutes2, Calendar.MINUTE);
cal.add(-minutes1, Calendar.MINUTE);
cal.add(seconds2 , Calendar.SECOND);
cal.add(-seconds1 , Calendar.SECOND);

int minuteDifference = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int secondDifference = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

This gives you the difference between the 2nd and the 1st time. Now use the same split and calendar mechanism to parse the third time and make the addition.

Comment: if it is a list of String Contains a mix of this Formats i need to calculate all in the list to get total in this format 00:00