# How to parse time durations from a list of Strings with 2 different Format and add them?

Tags: java

I Have a list of Strings with two different format e.g.

08:50 09:50

10:30

06:40 07:30

03:50 05:50

03:32

i need to iterate on them and subtract the first to be 01:00 & the third to be 00:50 and the fourth to be 02:00 and calculate to get the total for all of them to be 17:52 
N.B.
The list consist of thousands of records not these records only i need a generic solution please

Comment: Can you clarify what you don't understand from your last two question on the same topic? The only difference appears to be that you need a loop. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse time durations from Strings with 2 different Format and add them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795007/how-to-parse-time-durations-from-strings-with-2-different-format-and-add-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a regexp for filtering between the different types?

`\d\d:\d\d \d\d:\d\d` should be true for 08:50 09:50 but false for 10:30.

There are more than enough tutorials on reg exps online.

http://www.regexpal.com/ helps with builduing new expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the line and see what you get.

```
String[] parts = line.split(" ");
switch(parts.length) {
    case 1: 
        Date time = sdf.parse(parts[0]);
        // use time.
        break;
    case 2:
        Date time1 = sdf.parse(parts[0]);
        Date time2 = sdf.parse(parts[1]);
        // use time1 and time2
        break;
    default:
        // invalid line.
}
```