# Adding minutes to Time object in Java

Tags: java, spring, time

I am using Java to interact with a MySQL database that contains [Time type values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html). I can read this directly into Java [Time objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) by using the getTime() method from the [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) class.

**How can I add a number of minutes to the current Time object?**

I am not allowed to use Joda Time or other external libraries nor change the database types.

I have read everything I could find ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015536/java-how-to-add-10-mins-in-my-time), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759036/how-to-convert-string-into-time-format-and-add-two-hours) and many others) but none of the responses actually use Time objects.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015536/java-how-to-add-10-mins-in-my-time

Comment: That does not use Time objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Time extends Date` so you can use the techniques involving the `Date` and `Calendar` APIs.

```
import static java.util.Calendar.MINUTE;

...

final Time t = ... your Time instance ...;
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(t);
c.add(MINUTE, 10);
t.setTime(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

...keeping your fingers crossed that this didn't mess up something with the time zones/daylight saving time transitions.

Answer (score 3):

Since SQL Time object only store milliseconds now (everything else is deprecated) you can simply convert it to a Calendar object and add minutes to that like so:

```
Time mySqlTimeObject = getTime();

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(mySqlTimeObject.getTime());
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 10);

Time myNewSqlTimeObject = new Time(cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can convert Time to java.util.Date, for example:

```
        Time time = new Time (12,1,1);
        Date date = new Date(time.getTime());

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);


        time = new Time (cal.getTime().getTime());
```